# Why JWT token not secured?

Tags: java, jwt

I am using `JWT` token in my `spring boot` project. I am surprised that my JWT token decoded from their official website and all data recovered from token. 
Here is my token
 `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJTdGVlbERvYyIsImV4cCI6MTU1NzU2ODQ1MiwibG9naW5JZCI6ImFkbWluIiwidXNlcklkIjoyLCJlbWFpbElkIjoiZGhpcmVuZHJhQHRlc3QuY29tIn0.o4UKtwO22cAXLjIsUuDRgAQf7OjUbe_O9DbSGxPYgfQ`

Link where it's decoded [link..](https://www.jsonwebtoken.io/)

Here is my code

```
public class JwtHelper {

static String subject = "SteelDoc";
static String secret = "faa76006-6fef-413d-9cae-a05e63170cbf";

Integer userId = null;
String loginId = "";
String emailId = "";

public String getUserName() {
    return loginId;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.loginId = userName;
}

public Integer getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getToken(String loginId, Integer userId, String email) {
    try {
        Date d = new Date();
        Date de = d;
        de.setYear(de.getYear() + 1);
        String jwt = Jwts.builder().setSubject(subject).setExpiration(de).claim("loginId", loginId)
                .claim("userId", userId).claim("emailId", email)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret.getBytes("UTF-8")).compact();
        return jwt;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public boolean validateToken(String token) {
    String jwt = token;
    Jws<Claims> claims;
    try {
        claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret.getBytes("UTF-8")).parseClaimsJws(jwt);
        userId = (Integer) claims.getBody().get("userId");
        loginId = (String) claims.getBody().get("loginId");
        emailId = (String) claims.getBody().get("emailId");
        return true;
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}}
```

My questions are...

1. Why it is happening.?
2. If it is not secure then why we use it.?
3. Is there any way to secure this token.?

Comment: 1. Because that is supposed to happen. 2. It is secure, tampering with it will fail as it cannot be signed again (validation of signature will fail). 3. it is already secure.

Comment: I know it is secured and it sends in Authorization header from the client but if someone copy that token and decode it then he can be got my credentials(May have id and password)

Comment: If you need to protect data from being seen by unauthorized party, you need to use encryption. I think you should spend a lot more time studying the subject, if you do not understand difference between signing and encrypting.

Comment: How someone will decode your token without the key?

Comment: Like above put my token on that link `Link where it's decoded link..`

Comment: You shouldn't put things like a password in a JWT that is not what a JWT is for or how it should be used. So if you don't put that in your token don't worry, if you do remove it from the token. Also your token should have a limited lifetime, that way when someone obtains the token it is only valid for a short period of time.

Comment: Yeah after knowing this i will never put  password in token